# Nerd Fonts aggregate fonts don't work on Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

I'm having problems visualising Nerd Fonts on the Ubuntu Gnome terminal. I can correctly configure the fonts in the terminal, but it doesn't show aggregate fonts, only icons.

As an example, this is a screenshot using NeoVim:

[image]

As shown in the image, the file icons are visualised correctly in the tree on the right side of the screen, but the pipe |> is not merged into one single character.

The characters are correctly merged in the Windows Terminal using Ubuntu 22.04 with WSL2:

[image]

I'm running the following configuration on a virtual machine running on Windows:

- OS: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
- Terminal: Gnome Terminal
- Font selected: JetBrains Mono Nerd Font Regular

I can edit the question with more information if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term for "problems visualizing" in this case is "Ligature Support".

[image: Here's a screenshot of my typing echo |> into two terminals]

The top terminal is `kitty`, which does have ligature support, and the bottom terminal is `gnome-terminal` which does not have ligature support.

There's already an issue for `vte`, the library that handles the terminal backend for `gnome-terminal`, to handle ligatures. It's not complete at this time.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/192

The FiraCode page has a list of terminals that do support ligatures, and "Windows Terminal" is one that works.

https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#terminal-compatibility-list

Personally, I've been using `kitty` for years and it works great.
Using the Ligature support patch on `st` also looks interesting for a very minimal terminal.

https://st.suckless.org/patches/ligatures/

The size of your icons on the right side `NvimTree` window is very small. Please update your post with a close up of that character. To my eyes, the circled thing on the right looks the same in both images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just to add a note, the two icons on the right are indeed the same, I circled them in red to highlight that in both terminals the icons were appearing (so the terminals do take the font family in the configuration), but not the ligatures.